# How to "reset" a listview and show again the @android:id/empty when repopulating

Tags: android, listview

All my listviews in my application are using the empty property to show a progressdialog while loading some web content:

```
    <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@android:id/empty" android:gravity="center">
                <ProgressBar android:id="@+id/progressBar1" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></ProgressBar>
    </RelativeLayout>
    <ListView android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

This is great and work fine the first time, but unfortunately, if I want to reload the listview, I expect the progressdialog to show again!

but, I can use:

```
getListView().setAdapter(null);
```

or

```
getListView().setAdapter(new TweetItemAdapter(getActivity(),R.layout.row_tweet,new ArrayList<Tweet>()));
```

I xon't get any dialog, just an empty view.

So basically my question is "how to show the empty layout again during the second loading of the listview?

EDIT: With comment below, I tried :

```
    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        TweetItemAdapter test = (TweetItemAdapter) getListView().getAdapter();
        if(test != null){
            test.clear();
            test.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
        loadTweets(this, getListView());
    }
```

Still doesn't show the progressdialog, I get an empty view while loading. (EXCEPT for first loading that works perfectly)

Comment: I think you need to remove all items from the adapter, call `notifyDataSetChanged()` and that should show the empty.  Then you can set the adapter to null and do whatever.

Comment: just tried your idea with my edit in the question, is that what you proposed?

Comment: Yeah, that's basically what I was proposing.  Sorry it didn't work. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Approach:* Add in you XML the view that you want to show up when the `ListView` is empty. Then when populating the `ListView` check for the length of the data supplier you use in you adapter inside the `getView()` method (if it is null or its length is 0) if it is `null/0-length` then instantiate that view and change its visibility to `View.VISIBLE`. Or use `getListView().setEmptyView(findViewById(R.id.myemptyview));`

*Remark:* I think there is no need to clear you adapter `test.clear()` since (I assume somewhere in `loadTweets()` you have adapter and call `notifyDataSetChanged()` again) the listview will repopulate with the new data.

*Question:* Do you reinstantiate the progress dialog whenever you call `notifyDataSetChanged()` because my logic says that: progress dialog must be shown whenever you do fetching, i.e repopulating the listview with data? (I might be wrong)